Getting hostname from IP (on LAN) programmatically. Tried three methods, neither worked
I've been looking through questions and solutions to my problem (getting hostnames from a set of IPs on iOS) for a few days. Only three IP resolution methods seem to be listed for anyone, and neither worked for me, for different reasons.
Method 1: using NSHost
[[NSHost currentHost] names]

Problem with method 1: NSHost is NOT useable on iOS - only macOS
Method 2: using POSIX getaddrinfo
+(NSString *)getHostFromIPAddress:(NSString*)ipAddress {
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    int error;
    struct addrinfo *results = NULL;

    error = getaddrinfo([ipAddress cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL, &results);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        NSLog (@"Could not get any info for the address");
        return @""; // or exit(1);
    }
    
    NSString *resString = @"";
    

    for (struct addrinfo *r = results; r; r = r->ai_next)
    {
        char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = {0};
        error = getnameinfo(r->ai_addr, r->ai_addrlen, hostname, sizeof hostname, NULL, 0 , 0);
        if (error != 0)
        {
            continue; // try next one
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog (@"Found hostname: %s", hostname);
            return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hostname];;
            break;
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(results);
    return @"";
}

@end

Problem with method 2: instead of hostnames, it returns the same IP address it was given.
Method 3: using CFHostRef (the most popular method)
+(NSString *)getHostFromIPAddress:(NSString*)ipAddress {
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    
    int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([ipAddress cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (errorStatus != 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (addressRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    
    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
    if (hostRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFRelease(addressRef);
    
    BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
    if (!succeeded) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
        [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
    }
    
    return hostnames[0];
}

@end

Problem with method 3: succeeded is ALWAYS false. Getting the hostname never works with this method.
Method sources: Get host name From IP address iOS 10, how to resolve the hostname of a device in my LAN from its ip address on this LAN?, Get the list of devices with their hostnames and ip addresses on LAN in iOS swift 5
Tried code from every one of them, all failed.
Is it possible to fix any of the methods above or use different ones?
Using iPhone 15 (simulator).

It is not generally possible to do this. To get a host name for an ip address requires that the reverse domain lookup (for a host 1.2.3.4 this is 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa) is set up in DNS. This will not be the case for most home LANs. It may be set up in enterprise networks where the DHCP server can take care of this.

Some devices may also support SNMP, but you need to know the appropriate community string to access the data. There may also be other methods such as Bonjour/mDNS advertisements from some devices but there is no general method apart from reverse dns.

@Paulw11 thank you. is it possible to do this indirectly? to read the whole hostname-to-ip table for the local network, then reverse and use it?
And I am already reading mDNS advertisements, but they still don't give hostnames for most devices on LAN

Most local networks don't have a forward dns either, but even if it did, no, you can't initiate a zone transfer without authentication.

@Paulw11 can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?
